# Simple MySQL join using no indexes

Tags: mysql, join

The query below takes about 0.3 seconds. Why? And how can I solve it. The shouldnt take so long...

```
SELECT tshops.OfficialName
 , tresults.StartTime
 , tresults.Price
 , tresults.shopID
FROM
 tresults
INNER JOIN tshops
ON tshops.shopID = tresults.shopID
WHERE
  tresults.pID = 15
  AND tresults.websiteID = 1
  AND tresults.StartTime = (SELECT max(tresults.StartTime) AS maxstarttime
                        FROM
                          tresults
                        WHERE
                          tshops.shopID = tresults.shopID
                          AND tresults.pID = 15
                          AND tresults.websiteID = 1)
ORDER BY
  tresults.Price DESC
```

Explain result:

```
1, PRIMARY, tshops, ALL, PRIMARY, , , , 203, Using temporary; Using filesort
1, PRIMARY, tresults, eq_ref, PRIMARY,idxPID,idxWebsite,idxStartTimeASC,idxStartTimeDESC,fk_shopID, PRIMARY, 20, func,const,pricegrabber.tshops.shopID,const, 1, Using where
2, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, tresults, ref, idxPID,idxWebsite,fk_shopID, fk_shopID, 4, pricegrabber.tshops.shopID, 891, Using where; Using index
```

So a full table scan on tshops is done. But why? There's an index on shopID in both tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect the subselect which refers to the outer select is confusing matters.

Try doing a join against the subselect, using a GROUP BY on the shopID. Normally I would expect MySQL to optimise things to do this anyway, but worth a try.

Something like this (please excuse any typos)

```
SELECT tshops.OfficialName
 , tresults.StartTime
 , tresults.Price
 , tresults.shopID
FROM  tresults
INNER JOIN tshops
ON tshops.shopID = tresults.shopID
INNER JOIN (SELECT shopID, MAX(tresults.StartTime) AS MaxStartTime 
            FROM tresults 
            WHERE tresults.pID = 15 
            AND tresults.websiteID = 1 
            GROUP BY shopID) Sub1
ON tresults.StartTime = Sub1.MaxStartTime
WHERE
  tresults.pID = 15
  AND tresults.websiteID = 1
ORDER BY
  tresults.Price DESC
```

Comment: Great! That did the trick, thanks! But I still find those subselect joins hard to get my head around...

Comment: I just think of them as though the SQL in the subselect had created a table against which you want to join (internally I suppose that is what it does do). Hence it is just a simple piece of SQL.
Having to deal with MS Access in the past (which being polite is very limited in its support for subselects and joins) has possibly made it appear more logical to me.